how to replace the last n occurences of string using sed
I can replace the third occurrence of a string with:
sed 's/OLD/NEW/3'

or, with the GNU implementation of sed, all occurrences starting from the third with:
sed 's/OLD/NEW/3g'

But how do I replace the last 3 (or n) occurrences?

Please edit your question and add an example input and expected output so we can be sure to give you working solutions.

Although there is no direct sed option for this operation, here is a practical approach: replace the last occurrence of the string with:
$ sed -E 's/(.*)OLD/\1NEW/' input_file

As n is usually small you can simply pipe this into the same command n times:
$ sed -E 's/(.*)OLD/\1NEW/' input_file | sed -E 's/(.*)OLD/\1NEW/' | sed -E 's/(.*)OLD/\1NEW/'

or more simply repeat this command n times:
$ sed -Ei 's/(.*)OLD/\1NEW/' input_file

(note that in this case the input_file changes)

The simplest way to change the last three instances of a string that matches a specific pattern is to reverse each line of input and replace the reversed string:
$ echo 'this OLD is OLD OLD OLD!' | rev | sed -e 's/DLO/WEN/' -e 's/DLO/WEN/' -e 's/DLO/WEN/' | rev
this OLD is NEW NEW NEW!

There might be better ways of doing this if the specific format of the relevant lines is known. For example, in the test string I use above, we could simply have replaced OLD OLD OLD with NEW NEW NEW.
Note too that since regular expressions are applied in a left-to-right direction, replacing the reversed string may require a different pattern than the naive reversal of the original expression.  As an example, consider that replacing the first two letters in abab, when reversed must replace the last two letters in baba.

Reversing a line can be done with sed like this, using @ as a pivot character to divide the string up into an unreversed and a reversed part:
:loop
s/^\([^@]\)\([^@]*\)@\{0,1\}\(.*\)/\2@\1\3/
t loop
s/@//


Beware that for a s/xx/yy/ for instance echo xxx xxx xxx | rev | sed -e 's/xx/yy/' -e 's//yy/' -e 's//yy/' | rev yields xyy xyy xyy instead of yyx yyx yyx.

For s/bcd/abc/, see also $ echo 'bcd bcd bcddd' | rev | sed -e 's/dcb/cba/' -e 's//cba/' -e 's//cba/' | rev giving bcd bcd aaabc instead of abc abc abcdd.

@StéphaneChazelas Yes, some care has to be given to the new task of replacing the reversed string.  A mechanical reversal is not always the correct thing as the regular expression is applied in a left-to-right manner, which influences the outcome.  I will make a note about this in the answer.

One approach could be:
sed '
  # replace *all* OLDs with newline:
  s/OLD/\
/g
  :1
    # replace one newline back to a OLD as long as it is
    # followed by at least 3 newlines, relying on the fact
    # that the first .* will match greedily as much as possible.
    s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\n.*\n.*\n\)/\1OLD\2/

    # repeat as long as the above was successful:
  t1
  # replace the remaining newlines with NEW:
  s/\n/NEW/g'

With perl, doing the substitution twice, once and without change to record the number of occurrences, and a second time to replace only the (n-2)th to nth occurrences:
perl -pe '$n = s/OLD/$&/g; s/OLD/--$n < 3 ? "NEW" : $&/ge'

For arbitrary strings and max number of occurrences:
perl -spe '$n = s/\Q$old\E/$&/g;
           s/\Q$old\E/--$n < $max ? $new : $&/ge
          ' -- -old=OLD -new=NEW -max=3

s/OLD/$&/g replaces all occurrences with themselves ($& contains what was matched like sed's &) and returns the number of substitutions. Alternatively, you can use s/OLD\K//g which replaces the nothing after OLD with nothing, \K being used to mark the start of what is being replaced.

Using GNU awk for patsplit():
$ echo 'OLDOLDOLDOLDOLD' |
    awk '
        {
            nf = patsplit($0,f,"OLD",s)
            out = s[0]
            for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
                out = out ( i>(nf-3) ? "NEW" : f[i] ) s[i]
            }
            print out
        }
    '
OLDOLDNEWNEWNEW

You can do the same in any awk with a while (match()) or while(index()) and substr()s loop, it's just a bit more code to write. The above treats OLD as a regexp, if that's not what you want then use a while(index()) loop instead or write code to escape any metachars OLD might contain, e.g. in any awk using literal strings:
echo 'OLDOLDOLDOLDOLD' |
    awk -v old="OLD" -v new="NEW" -v cnt=3 '
        {
            nf = strsplit($0,f,old,s)
            out = s[0]
            for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
                out = out ( i>(nf-cnt) ? "NEW" : f[i] ) s[i]
            }
            print out
        }

        function strsplit(str,flds,tgt,seps,    pos,cnt,lgth)    {
            lgth = length(tgt)
            while ( pos = index(str,tgt) ) {
                seps[cnt++] = substr(str,1,pos-1)
                flds[cnt]   = substr(str,pos,lgth)
                str         = substr(str,pos+lgth)
            }
            seps[cnt] = str
            return cnt+0
        }
    '
OLDOLDNEWNEWNEW

